# Flask-jwt and Flask-resftul error handling

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-jwt

I'm using [flask-jwt](http://flask-jwt.readthedocs.org) and [flask-restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/)

This is how flask-jwt handling errors(taken from its github repo) but none of them let me take the parameters of JWTError.

```
if auth is None:
        raise JWTError('Authorization Required', 'Authorization header was missing', 401, {
            'WWW-Authenticate': 'JWT realm="%s"' % realm
        })

parts = auth.split()

if parts[0].lower() != auth_header_prefix.lower():
    raise JWTError('Invalid JWT header', 'Unsupported authorization type')
elif len(parts) == 1:
    raise JWTError('Invalid JWT header', 'Token missing')
elif len(parts) > 2:
    raise JWTError('Invalid JWT header', 'Token contains spaces')

try:
    handler = _jwt.decode_callback
    payload = handler(parts[1])
except SignatureExpired:
        raise JWTError('Expired JWT', 'Token is expired', 401, {
            "WWW-Authenticate": 'JWT realm="{0}"'.format(realm)
        })
except BadSignature:
        raise JWTError('Invalid JWT', 'Token is undecipherable')

_request_ctx_stack.top.current_user = user = _jwt.user_callback(payload)

if user is None:
    raise JWTError('Invalid JWT', 'User does not exist')
```

And the following are the different ways how I try to handle JWTError

In flask:

```
def handle_user_exception_again(e):
    if isinstance(e, JWTError):
        data = {'status_code': 1132, 'message': "JWTError already exists."}
        return jsonify(data), e.status_code, e.headers
    return e

app.handle_user_exception = handle_user_exception_again
```

In flask-restful (handle_error)

```
class FlaskRestfulJwtAPI(Api):

def handle_error(self, e):
    if isinstance(e, JWTError):
        code = 400
        data = {'status_code': code, 'message': "JWTError already exists."}
    elif isinstance(e, KeyError):
        code = 400
        data = {'status_code': code, 'message': "KeyError already exists."}
    else:
        # Did not match a custom exception, continue normally
        return super(FlaskRestfulJwtAPI, self).handle_error(e)
    return self.make_response(data, code)
```

In flask-restful (error_router)

```
class FlaskRestfulJwtAPI(Api):

def error_router(self, original_handler, e):
    print(type(e))
    if e is JWTError:#KeyError:
        data =  {
                "code":400,
                "message":"JWTError"
            }
        return jsonify(data), 400
    elif isinstance(e,KeyError):
        data =  {
            "code":400,
            "message":"KeyError"
        }
        return jsonify(data), 400
    else:
        return super(FlaskRestfulJwtAPI, self).error_router(original_handler, e)
```

Comment: Nice summary, but what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to raise an HTTPException from these errors, which helps with returning them to users. To raise an HTTP exception, you can catch all errors and if they are an instance of a JWTError, you can convert them to an instance of an HTTPException using a function like the following:

```
def convert_to_http_exception(e):
    if isinstance(e, JWTError):
        jwtdescription = e.error + ": " + e.description
        http_exception = HTTPException(description=jwtdescription)
        http_exception.code = e.status_code
        return http_exception
    else:
        return e
```